# Vue Uncaught RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: vue.js

when i build my `vue project`, browser always throw error: `Uncaught RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded`, no matter it is in proxy environment or not.

versions:

```
*vue@ 2.1.8
*vue-router@2.1.1
*vue-loader@9.8.0
```

Comment: What are you doing to cause that error? Could you show some code? uncaught range errors are usually the result of infinite loops or recursive functions.

Comment: are you console.logging a computed property in its definition?

Comment: Thanks Amresh for your attentions. when i change some codes and save my files, this erroe happen.

Comment: i tried to pasted my codes here, but failed; <br> here is my project link (https://github.com/abbymrs/vue-demo.git);

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit too late but for future use.

This happened to me several times due to a repeated navigation into a missing link.

in my navigation guard

```
beforeEach({})
```

I was navigating to

```
next('/dashboard')
```

but this route wasn't defined (in my case i had removed it).

Make sure all the navigation point into a valid route path or name.